# Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]-usingAbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

this is  my initializer class

```
public class AppInitializer  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    System.out.println("root configuration has been started");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class[] {JerseyServlet.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class[] {};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[]{"/"};
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("Appinitialization has been started");
    super.onStartup(container);
    container.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
}
```

}

and this is JerseyServlet class

```
@Configuration
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="com.example.webservice")

public class JerseyServlet extends SpringServlet{

      public JerseyServlet(){
                System.out.println("Jersy Sevlet has been called========");
            }
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        }
```

Error stack trace is

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)

Comment: It cannot find `/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml` post you project structure, check whether the file exists and correctly copied to be available.

Comment: Have you tried without "implements WebApplicationInitializer" in your config initializer class?

Comment: instead of dispatcher-servlet.xml i am using AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer @ StainslavL

Comment: Yes , I already tried without WebApplicationInitializer .It is not working @ K.D

Comment: Will you post your pom.xml?